# Got an error message Syntax Error in ansible-playbook

Tags: ansible

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/main.yml': line 73, column 50, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: Ensure IP forwarding is disabled
  shell: "sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward ; grep "net\.ipv4\.ip_forward" /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/*"
                                             ^ here
```

We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
unbalanced quotes.  If starting a value with a quote, make sure the
line ends with the same set of quotes.  For instance this arbitrary
example:

I using grep with "" into shell module in ansible playbook and got an ERROR message as follow "ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML."

```
- name: Ensure IP forwarding is disabled
  shell: "sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward ; grep "net\.ipv4\.ip_forward" /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/*"
  register: CIS_3.1.1
  ignore_errors: True
```

Comment: Hi Rick_y, welcome to SO. I hope you can appreciate that just like any programming language, you need to escape a double-quote that appears in a double-quoted string. If you don't want to escape them, then you can switch to using single quotes around your shell command: `- shell: 'sysctl net ...grep "net\...'`. Separately, there is an [ansible module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/sysctl_module.html#sysctl-module) for doing what you are doing by hand

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It is not enough to escape the double quotes in your scalar,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That configuration file for ansible is in the YAML format and in YAML a scalar that represents a string can be in multiple formats:

- plain: no quotes, has restrictions on the start character and internal character sequences, no escapes
- single quoted: can contain double quotes, no escapes except for repeating single quotes
- double quoted: backslash escapes in string, in string double quotes need to be escaped
- literal: newlines are preserved, no escapes
- folded: newlines are converted to spaces, no escapes

You are using double quoted style, and in that you would need to escape the internal double quotes (`"`) and backslashes (`\`). That gets ugly and unreadble real soon. It is much more useful to use literal style in such cases:

```
- name: Ensure IP forwarding is disabled
  shell: |-
    sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward ; grep "net\.ipv4\.ip_forward" /etc/sysctl.conf /etc/sysctl.d/*
```

I.e. you put `|-` (the minus is to strip the final newline of the following line), then put the line without starting or end quotes, **indented**, on the next line.